# What do I need to develop for a Vending Machine that uses the MDB protocol?

Tags: multidrop-bus

I have a project with a Vending Machine. The documentation says that the machine uses the MDB protocol (a standard protocol for [vending machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidrop_bus)).

How do I develop an application to interact with the machine, and, for example, change the price of a product?

What tools and API's do I need?

Comment: Does the manufacturer not have a development suite available?

Comment: Do you know the make (manufacturer) and model number for the vending machine that you are developing for?

Comment: I have the same problem. I have an MEI Cashflow 7900 that can communicate using MDB. As far as I know, it is connected to the host machine using an MDB loom. The vendor didn't include any sample applications/diagnostics tools. All that was included was the MDB protocol specification document. I'm trying to interface with the MEI CF7900 using C# but have not been successful thus far. Does anyone know of any APIs or sample applications that communicate with a device over MDB? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You need to have an interface connector, such as the one at http://www.waferstar.com/en/MDB-PC.html as the MDB interface isn't native RS-232.

Answer (score 1):

MDB is a a simple 9 bit serial interface, with a single controller and multiple slaves. A 9bit UART capable of 9600bps is all you need. Bill changers, CC readers, etc are all slaves. You can find the spec online:

www.vending.org/technical/MDB_3.0.pdf

Note that the vending machine itself contains the controller,   and all of the controllers have their own peculiarities.

Comment: You can also search for "Virtual MDB Test Box User Guide".   It will give you an introduction to the some of the commands and configuration information that allow the controller to communicate with the slave peripherals.

Comment: Please edit your original answer with the link and your additional comments, and then delete this answer.